# RHEL 8 - Is there a replacement for 'krb5-server'?

Tags: redhat, kerberos, rhel8

I've got an old Dockerfile, based on Ubuntu, that installs `krb5-server` as a dependency via `apt`.

I'd like to update the Dockerfile and base it on RHEL 8 instead, but `krb5-server` doesn't seem to be available in `yum`.

I've found a few articles online (like [this one](https://www.stigviewer.com/stig/red_hat_enterprise_linux_8/2022-12-06/finding/V-237640) that suggest that it had vulnerabilities, so I guess it got pulled from `yum`'s catalog.

Does anyone know if there's a replacement for it, or can you just not install a Kerberos server in RHEL 8 at the moment?

Answer (score 0):

> *... but `krb5-server` doesn't seem to be available in `yum`.*

I am not able to reproduce your observation. In an almost out-of-box installation

```sh
cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.8 (Ootpa)
```

the command `yum provides krb5-server` just reports

```sh
krb5-server-1.18.2-14.el8.x86_64 : The KDC and related programs for Kerberos 5
Repo        : rhel-8-for-x86_64-baseos-rpms
Matched from:
Provide    : krb5-server = 1.18.2-14.el8
```

The package seems to be available from within `rhel-8-for-x86_64-baseos-rpms`.

> *... so I guess it got pulled from `yum`'s catalog.*

No, this indicates an issue somewhere else in your setup and configuration, mainly your subscription.

Furthermore, the Security Technical Implementation Guides (STIGs) you are referencing are regarding [FIPS 140-2 cryptography](https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/how-rhel-8-designed-fips-140-2-requirements) and RHEL 8 and the packages are in [Support Lifecycle](https://access.redhat.com/support/policy/updates/errata#RHEL8_and_9_Life_Cycle) and get Security Updates.

**How to proceed further?**

You may have a look into threads regarding `subscription-manager` first. In example

```yaml
~$ sudo subscription-manager status
+-------------------------------------------+
   System Status Details
+-------------------------------------------+
Overall Status: Current

System Purpose Status: Not Specified

~$ sudo subscription-manager list
+-------------------------------------------+
    Installed Product Status
+-------------------------------------------+
Product Name:   Red Hat Enterprise Linux for x86_64
Product ID:     479
Version:        8.8
Arch:           x86_64
Status:         Subscribed
Status Details:
Starts:         01/01/2021
Ends:           01/01/2024
```

Do **Further Reading**

- [How does Red Hats `subscription-manager` work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58060882/)
- [Subscription Manager `list` shows `Status Details: Not covered by a valid subscription`](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/653533)

and research on it.

Comment: Thanks for your help @U880D.
You've confirmed my suspicion that the docker image (ubi8 in this case) needs to be connected to a subscription manager to get that particular package.
I wasn't sure how that worked in docker images (I don't usually use RHEL), but I guess I do need it after all. I'll see if I can find a way to register my builds with the server.